# How to save files from a website using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to save several files from a site to my Google Drive automatically.

I can retrieve links like :

```
http://www.somesitename/download.aspx?Type=DD&ID=4725aea4-675d-45f5-b20d-dc0cb12389ee
```

How can I download this file to my Google Drive using Google Apps Script?

Remark : Can I avoid the popupbox asking if I want to open or save the file (other then checking the 'Do this automatically for files like this from now on')

Comment: What is the trigger to save the file automatically?  What is the process?

Comment: I want to download (and process) files from the website of our local community periodically.Probably I'll check for changes every day. This will be performed in a batchoperation so nobody will be sitting bat the keyboard hitting the enter key to store the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're in the habit of posting here before doing a Google search or looking at the documentation.

Anyways, use a combinatino of the [Url Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/) and Drive API after enabling it in advanced services.

```
var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://i.imgur.com/ahDXEPo.png').getBlob();
var file = {
  title: 'some_image.png',
  mimeType: 'image/png'
};
file = Drive.Files.insert(file, image);
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, but you're wrong about the first line you wrote : I do (and did) look at docs but it was not all clear to me because of the popupbox for saving. Apart from that, if every question that has been asked before and documented would never be asked again I guess the world would be a quiet place. Now I have it running, but I still have a problem with comparing blobs in order to update content if required and not creating a new file if already present.